# Iterate through columns to sum the previous 2 numbers of each row

Tags: r, loops, iteration, apply, lapply

In R, I have a dataframe, with columns 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'. The columns have 100 rows.

I need to iterate through the columns to perform a calculation for all rows in the dataframe which sums the previous 2 rows of that column, and then set in new columns ('AA', 'AB', etc) what that sum is:

```
A  B  C  D 
1  2  3  4
2  3  4  5
3  4  5  6
4  5  6  7 
5  6  7  8
6  7  8  9
```

to

```
A   B   C   D   AA   AB   AC   AD
1   2   3   4   NA   NA   NA   NA
2   3   4   5   3    5    7    9
3   4   5   6   5    7    9    11
4   5   6   7   7    9    11   13
5   6   7   8   9    11   13   15
6   7   8   9   11   13   15   17
```

Can someone explain how to create a function/loop that allows me to set the columns I want to iterate over (selected columns, not all columns) and the columns I want to set?

Answer (score 2):

A `base` one-liner:

```
cbind(df, setNames(df + df[c(NA, 1:(nrow(df)-1)), ], paste0("A", names(df))))
```

If your data is large, this one might be the fastest because it manipulates the entire `data.frame`.

---

A `dplyr` solution using `mutate()` with `across()`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(across(A:D,
                ~ .x + lag(.x),
                .names = "A{col}"))

#   A B C D AA AB AC AD
# 1 1 2 3 4 NA NA NA NA
# 2 2 3 4 5  3  5  7  9
# 3 3 4 5 6  5  7  9 11
# 4 4 5 6 7  7  9 11 13
# 5 5 6 7 8  9 11 13 15
# 6 6 7 8 9 11 13 15 17
```

If you want to sum the previous 3 rows, the second argument of `across()`, i.e. `.fns`, should be

```
~ .x + lag(.x) + lag(.x, 2)
```

which is equivalent to the use of `rollsum()` in `zoo`:

```
~ zoo::rollsum(.x, k = 3, fill = NA, align = 'right')
```

---

***Benchmark***

A benchmark test with `microbenchmark` package on a new `data.frame` with 10000 rows and 100 columns and evaluate each expression for 10 times.

```
# Unit: milliseconds
#                     expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq        max neval
#              darren_base   18.58418   20.88498   35.51341   33.64953   39.31909   80.24725    10
#         darren_dplyr_lag   39.49278   40.27038   47.26449   42.89170   43.20267   76.72435    10
# arg0naut91_dplyr_rollsum  436.22503  482.03199  524.54800  516.81706  534.94317  677.64242    10
#    Grothendieck_rollsumr 3423.92097 3611.01573 3650.16656 3622.50895 3689.26404 4060.98054    10
```

Comment: that's a good approach except if he needs something more complicated and less regular than a rolling sum then the whole code breaks

Comment: @ivan866 I don't think so. With the `.fns` argument in `across()`, or the `FUN` argument in `lapply()`, we can customize any complicated functions we want.

Comment: that gonna be a cell-wise calculation, not vectorized -> slow

Comment: loop approach also has enormous memory usage

Comment: it is interesting that i also sometimes get @pseudospin's `dt` solution is actually 0.1% SLOWER than yours if ran 1 time, but faster 37-69% if ran repetitiously. could be related to DT's `memmap` behavior. im testing on `R` 3.5.1 btw; `data.table` 1.11.4

Comment: It's a little unfair that you're making a copy of the data in my version for each loop... but still, it's interesting that even in spite of that the data.table version is slower for you than for me (it's twice as fast if I just copy your code above). Must be platform dependent in some way.

Comment: @pseudospin, what if we convert all answers to form  
f.name <- function(df) {  
<function body>  
return df  
}  and bench them again with latest lib builds

Comment: I'd just take the first 3 lines of mine outside the benchmarking, but you might argue that's unfair too. It's really that data.table is modifying in place which makes it hard to compare them.

Comment: @pseudospin yes you are right! I just wanna show that my `base` way is slower but close to your `data.table` one despite this large data. Glad to discuss with you and ivan866.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dplyr`'s `across` (and set optional names) with rolling sum (as implemented e.g. in `zoo`):

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

df %>%
  mutate(
    across(
      A:D,
      ~ rollsum(., k = 2, fill = NA, align = 'right'), 
      .names = 'A{col}'
    )
  )
```

Output:

```
  A B C D AA AB AC AD
1 1 2 3 4 NA NA NA NA
2 2 3 4 5  3  5  7  9
3 3 4 5 6  5  7  9 11
4 4 5 6 7  7  9 11 13
5 5 6 7 8  9 11 13 15
6 6 7 8 9 11 13 15 17
```

With `A:D` we've specified the range of column names we want to apply the function to. The assumption above in `.names` argument is that you want to paste together `A` as prefix and the column name (`{col}`).

Answer (score 1):

That is a naive approach with nested `for` loops. Beware it is damn slow if you gonna iterate over hundreds thousand rows.

```
i <- 1
n <- 5
df <- data.frame(A=i:(i+n), B=(i+1):(i+n+1), C=(i+2):(i+n+2), D=(i+3):(i+n+3))
for (col in colnames(df)) {
  for (ind in 1:nrow(df)) {
    if (ind-1==0) {next}
    s <- sum(df[c(ind-1, ind), col])
    df[ind, paste0('S', col)] <- s
  }
}
```

That is a `cumsum` method:

```
na.df <- data.frame(matrix(NA, 2, ncol(df)))
colnames(na.df) <- colnames(df)
cs1 <- cumsum(df)
cs2 <- rbind(cs1[-1:-2,], na.df)
sum.diff <- cs2-cs1
cbind(df, rbind(na.df[1,], cs1[2,], sum.diff[1:(nrow(sum.diff)-2),]))
```

Benchmark:

```
#    Unit: milliseconds  
#                      expr     min       lq     mean   median       uq     max neval  
#          darrentsai.rbind 11.5623 12.28025 23.38038 16.78240 20.83420 91.9135   100  
#     darrentsai.rbind.rev1  8.8267  9.10945 15.63652  9.54215 14.25090 62.6949   100  
#             pseudopsin.dt  7.2696  7.52080 20.26473 12.61465 17.61465 69.0110   100  
#            ivan866.cumsum 25.3706 30.98860 43.11623 33.78775 37.36950 91.6032   100
```

I believe, most of the time the cumsum method wastes on df allocations. If correctly adapted to data.table backend, it could be the fastest.

Comment: I revise the use of `rbind()` and `head()`, which may get a little improvement.

Comment: @DarrenTsai, yes it is 32% better now, and still best on memory usage. congratulations

Answer (score 1):

Here's a data.table solution. As you ask for, it allows you to select which columns you want to apply it to rather than just for all columns.

```
library(data.table)
x <- data.table(A=1:6, B=2:7, C=3:8, D=4:9)
selected_cols <- c('A','B','D')
new_cols <- paste0("A",selected_cols)
x[, (new_cols) := lapply(.SD, function(col) col+shift(col, 1)), .SDcols = selected_cols]
x[]
```

NB This is 2 or 3 times faster than the fastest other answer.

Comment: very nice. i also was working on `data.table` solution but didnt know it has `shift` method. your solution is 37% faster, but it also consumes much more memory than @darren's `rbind` method

Answer (score 1):

Specify the columns we want.  We show several different ways to do that.  Then use `rollsumr` to get the desired columns, set the column names and cbind `DF` with it.

```
library(zoo)

# jx <- names(DF)  # if all columns wanted
# jx <- sapply(DF, is.numeric)  # if all numeric columns
# jx <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")  # specify columns by name
jx <- 1:4   # specify columns by position

r <- rollsumr(DF[jx], 2, fill = NA)
colnames(r) <- paste0("A", colnames(r))
cbind(DF, r)
```

giving:

```
  A B C D AA AB AC AD
1 1 2 3 4 NA NA NA NA
2 2 3 4 5  3  5  7  9
3 3 4 5 6  5  7  9 11
4 4 5 6 7  7  9 11 13
5 5 6 7 8  9 11 13 15
6 6 7 8 9 11 13 15 17
```

### Note

The input in reproducible form:

```
DF <- structure(list(A = 1:6, B = 2:7, C = 3:8, D = 4:9), 
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```